# In Contentpage the jquery is not firing

Tags: jquery

this is the plugin is used in masterpage for dropdown

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<ul class="nav pull-right custom-dropdown">
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkprofile" CssClass="lnkButton" Text="Profile" PostBackUrl="~/Admin/ViewProfile.aspx" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></li>
                                    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkchangepwd" CssClass="lnkButton" Text="Change Password" PostBackUrl="~/Admin/ChangePassword.aspx" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></li>
                                    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSignOut" CssClass="lnkButton" Text="Sign out" runat="server" OnClick="LnkSignOut_Click"></asp:LinkButton></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

I want to use the same plugin in Content Page

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


            $("#<%=txtbirth.ClientID %>").datepicker({


                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        yearRange: '1960:2030',
                        showOn: 'button',
                        buttonImage: "images/1315298127_calendar_1.png",
                        buttonImageOnly: true


           });
```

but it is not Inherting

Comment: Has your problem solved If not then check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code hanging without any script reference.

1) Enclose it using **`script`** tag

2) Enclose your code using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //your dp code
});
```

Comment: Part 2 is unnecessary... ;)

Comment: I added the script tag no result @user1671639

Comment: console means@user1671639

Comment: @AnushaNandialya Console is a place in browser where errors will be logged. In browser, Press f12 to open developer tools.  Then select **console** where the errors are logged.  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: @user1671639 There are no errors but the plugin is not inheriting from master page

Comment: @AnushaNandialya make sure your jQuery is getting added.  In first block of code I see `<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" t` whereas in second part `<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"`

Comment: @user1671639 in second block the Jquery is not firing.but it is working in first block

Comment: @AnushaNandialya how are you saying that it works for first block, I don't see any jQery/JS in your first block.  Can you clear this doubt

Comment: @user1671639 I used jquery/js in my file.the dropdown is working.

Comment: @AnushaNandialya weird. your code is perfect, which works in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TjLus/.  The problem is that you're missing adding the source script file

Answer (score 0):

Has your problem solved If not then try following code pls and do let me know if it is not working

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {



  $("#<%=txtbirth.ClientID %>").datepicker({

                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        yearRange: '1960:2030',
                        showOn: 'button',
                        buttonImage: "images/1315298127_calendar_1.png",
                        buttonImageOnly: true

           });


  });
  </script>
```